# Avoid vim to add bullet point when wrapping lines

Tags: vimrc

I'm not expert in vim at all but I like it a lot.

In my personal computer I've loaded the example_vimrc in my `.vimrc` and added some extra lines so when I type a bullet point and keep typing till 80 characters, vim automatically wraps my line an continues below like this

```
* This is an example line, just guess that the line break is at 80
  characters and when I keep typing vim do this great thing of
  indenting my lines like this.
```

In my job computer, I have the SAME .vimrc file but I managed to note that the condition '`if has ("autocmd")`' is not true and I don't know what happens (because I'm newbie) but when I type the kind of text like above I get the following

```
* This is an example of a line representing what happens in my job
* I'm not really pressing ENTER, and obviously I'm not typing a 
* bullet like '*' with each new line because this is the same note 
* but vim automatically adds a new '*' with each line wrap
```

How can I get rid of this behavior?? I already read a related post and tried to use the option 'set comments=' but I get the following behavior

```
* This is a line after setting 'set comments=' which removes the '*'
I think, but after line wrapping the indentation doesn't work and
the text keeps appearing like this, although if I manually add blank
  spaces like in THIS LINE and I keep typing then when vim wraps the
  line, automatically aligns the text like this, I hope it can give 
  you a clue of what is happening.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!, remember my .vimrc is the example_vimrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [*Disable automatic comment insertion*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion), you probably want to add this in your vimrc file:

```
:set formatoptions-=cro
```

From [`:h fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table):

```
You can use the 'formatoptions' option  to influence how Vim formats text.
'formatoptions' is a string that can contain any of the letters below. The
default setting is "tcq". You can separate the option letters with commas for
readability.

letter   meaning when present in 'formatoptions'

t        Auto-wrap text using textwidth
c        Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
         leader automatically.
r        Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
         <Enter> in Insert mode.
o        Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
         'O' in Normal mode.
```

---

**Edit**: Looks like you were on the right track, I should have dug in the `:set comments?` direction.

The default value is `s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-` (and for the record you replaced `mb:*` with `fb:*`).

Read [`:h format-comments`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format-comments) for more details:

```
The 'comments' option is a comma-separated list of parts. Each part defines a
type of comment string. A part consists of:
        {flags}:{string}

{string} is the literal text that must appear.

{flags}:

  m     Middle of a three-piece comment

  f     Only the first line has the comment string.  Do not repeat comment on
        the next line, but preserve indentation (e.g., a bullet-list).
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed, as your reply states 'The default setting is tcq'   I had default values and if I do ':set fo-=cro' nothing changes because the value is actually 'tcq' (not containing cro), thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe test with `vim -u NONE` and compare the `vim --version` on both machines (then edit your question). I wonder which `&filetype` is this?

Comment: vim version in my job machine is `7.4.52` and if I do `:set filetype?` when executed `vim -u NONE` the result is `filetype=`

Comment: Hey! I just discovered something, if I type '-' instead of '*' the behavior is the expected!! hope this helps

Comment: Glad you found out, happy vimming ;)

Comment: @Migdress If it works for you, please [mark the answer as accepted.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235)